# JavaFX stylesheets dynamically imported in stylemanager

Tags: java, css, resources, javafx, stylesheet

I'm developing a JavaFX application and I'm currently working on resources management. I achieved to create utility static class that provides fonts, images, etc for my application.
But I'm stuck on CSS loading.

My Util static class defines :

```
public static ArrayList<String> getStyleSheets() {
    return listAbsoluteFileNames(cssDir);
}

public static ArrayList<String> listAbsoluteFileNames(File dir) {
    File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<listOfFiles.length ; i++) {
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            list.add(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Where `cssDir` is a File object defining the directory "css" which contains my stylesheets. I wanted to load these files, but I got some errors.

In my Application subclass:

```
stage.getScene().getStylesheets().addAll(Resources.getStyleSheets());
```

Generated errors:

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged Resource "C:\Users\...\resources\css\main_menu.css" not found.
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged Resource "C:\Users\...\resources\css\main_menu.css" not found.
```

Solution 1: I can read the css files that I need in my panes to set style with the method "setStyle(/content of my css file/)" but I think it could be a better way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found solution, I wasn't using URL with my implementation. StyleManager loads files from specified path like :
file:///C:/.../file.css
I found solution on already discussed post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236641/javafx-add-dynamically-css-files

Answer (score 1):

I hope You found out by now, but I'll say it all the same to help whoever will search StackOverflow ;)

Problem is strings You pass to `stage.getScene().getStylesheets().addAll(...)` must represent URLs, while You pass over absolute filenames.
So your routine should really be:

```
public static ArrayList<String> listAbsoluteFileNames(File dir) {
    File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<listOfFiles.length ; i++) {
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            try {
                list.add(listOfFiles[i].toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // should never happen
            }
    }
    return list;
}
```