# How to create a stylesheet dynamically and add that to a node

Tags: css, javafx

Currently JavaFX does not allow attaching a stylesheet to a node (or scene) that is not in the classpath. So, if a css file is not in the classpath already, it cannot be added to any node. The getStyleSheets().add() method will state 'WARNING Resource [your file] not found'. So is there any workaround to this limitation?

Comment: For the record: I know about the setStyle method, but in this case i can't use it.

Comment: Why cant u use it ?

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236641/dynamically-add-css-stylesheets-in-javafx

Comment: I'm using a third party lib, and there is no API for setStyle.

Comment: @MeGoodGuy It's not my answer.

Comment: Sorry, if u're not developping directly with JavaFX we cant help

Comment: Write a new stlysheet in the code into a temporary directory (it is actually a text-file with .css extension), and then `node.getParent():getStyleSheets().add(tempfile); node.getStyleClass().add("my-temp-style-class");`.

Comment: If it is a JavaFX `Node` (or any subclass of it), it has a `setStyle(...)` method and a `getStyleClass()` method. If it's not a subclass of `Node`, you can't put it in the `Scene` or in a `Pane` anyway. Please be clear what you mean.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for...

```
Button node = new Button();
node.getStyleClass().add("my-new-style-class");

.my-new-style-class {
    -fx-padding: 5;
}
```

Comment: No, I want to define a style class in code, not a css file.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to create a temporary stlyesheet file, write the new style-class inside, add the style-sheet to the list of sheets of the node and add also the new style-class.

**Here is a working example:**

```
Button button = new Button("My Text");

button.setOnAction(e -> {

    try {
        // Create a new tempfile that will be removed as the application exits
        File tempStyleClass = File.createTempFile("AppXY_TempStyleClass", ".css");
        tempStyleClass.deleteOnExit();

        // Write the stlye-class inside
        try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(tempStyleClass)) {
            printWriter.println(".temp-style { -fx-text-fill: red; }");
        }

        // Add the style-sheet and the style-class to the node
        button.getStylesheets().add(tempStyleClass.toURI().toString());
        button.getStyleClass().add("temp-style");

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, It's late, 2 years late, but maybe it helps someone.

The idea is this:

```
object.setStyle("[your CSS code]");
```

Example to give a background color red to an object called "node":

```
node.setStyle("fx-background-color: red");
```

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");

Comment: 4 years late, this is not what the OP asked for. Adding a stylesheet to a node is not the same as setting the style.  For starters, setting the style removes all previous classes of that node, overwriting the cascadded classes with the current style. 

The answer from DVarga is correct.